# Coverity Prevent: how to handle "checked return" warning when I deliberately don't check the return?

Tags: coverity-prevent

As the title suggest, for example, in 85% of the situation, I'd like to check the return code of foo(), but sometimes I really don't care about it, but this will raise Coverity warning.

What's the best way to deal with this problem?
Changing Coverity settings doesn't count. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to suppress CHECKED_RETURN defect is to cast the return value you don't care about to a void.  This has the additional advantage of making it clear to anyone reading the code that you don't care about return value, rather than that you forgot to check it.

Comment: in addition, trying to trick analysis with macros will not work since Coverity is not analyzing the source code but rather the AST.

Comment: Coverity still flagged `(void)fread(..)` with this error for me after adding the cast to void. Perhaps the option doesn't work for syscalls/functions flagged 'always check'. It was legitimate though, a separate ferror() was covering the failure cases.

Comment: right, statistical checkers honor (void) but ones that are explicitly asked to be checked will flag failure to check even with attempt to suppress.  There is always comment annotations to suppress *those* when needed :)